# Where is the gcc executable under Linux?

Tags: linux, gcc, centos

I installed gcc 4.7.0 as a new version, but the result of `gcc --version` did not change. I learned that I should set a link in `/usr/bin/` to the gcc executable. However, under the index of 4.7.0 I installed there are 6 indexes:

```
bin include lib lib64 libexec share
```

I am not sure where I can find the gcc executable. Where should the gcc executable be commonly?

Thank you!

Comment: Have a try using the `find` utility, read about how to use it using the manual page: `man find`. On unixoid systems executables are traditionally found in the `bin` folder.

Comment: How did you install it? (What you call "indexes" seem to be directories.)

Comment: I installed it from gcc-4.7.0.tar.gz by running configure and make.

Answer (score 1):

It should be under the `/usr/bin` directory. If it is not, try to find with:

```
$ which gcc
```